# jQuery - if Value = 1 fadeIn

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any alternative to onKeyUp which says that if letter was typed do this because onKeyUp shift, enter, backspace etc counts.

Something like if value.div1 = 1 fade in div2 for example.

Thanks alot

EDIT:
Okay I wasn't clear. Sorry, what I meant is:

I have a textarea. If letter is typed [not KeyUP,Keypress etc.] in the textarea then fadeIn div1.

Sorry and thanks alot again

Comment: ???? I don't understand your question.

Comment: I don't know if I understand you, but you could ask what key was presed (keycodes: http://goo.gl/IR4SU):
$('#target').keyup(function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode != '13') 
     //do something});

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following only does something for a letter key:

```
$("your selector here").keyup(function(event) {
  var key = event.which;
  if (key >= 65 && key <= 90) {
    // a letter key was pressed; 65=A, 90=Z
  }
});
```

The [jQuery `keyup` doco](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/) says, "For catching actual text entry, `.keypress()` may be a better choice." But having said that, all of the key handling events (up, down, press) let you see which key was pressed and decide whether or not to take action. The jQuery doco also explains the difference between `event.which`, `event.keyCode` and `event.charCode`, but note that for the `keyup` event the code will be the same regardless of whether an upper or lowercase character is type; for `keypress` the codes will be different for upper and lower.

A quick Google search found the following page which gives a chart of what keys go with each keycode: http://www.webonweboff.com/tips/js/event_key_codes.aspx - so obviously you could expand the little function I gave you to include other keys that you care about.

But did you really mean to ask about only letters, or do you care about the number keys, punctuation, etc., but not things like the arrow keys? You mentioned not wanting to handle shift, but you also said backspace and enter, both of which can change the value of a field, so your requirement is ambiguous. **What do you want to do if the user presses shift+insert and pastes some letters into your field?**

Comment: Just this code was my answer. It's a textarea where when you type a letter, a button fade's in which is a button to clear all field's values and then .focus().select on the textarea to start typing again. Thanks alot

Comment: it doesn't takes care of lowercase letters. And how abt numbers? I think what we need here is detecting keyUp only when thr is visible change in the text written in the box

Comment: @a6hi5h3k - the code I posted does take care of lowercase letters. The `keyup` and `keydown` events have keycodes mapped to the keys, not mapped to the set of characters. So lower and upper case A are both 65. "{" and "[" will have the same keycode too, given that (on most keyboards) they're on the same key. The `keypress` event will give you different codes for upper and lower case.

Comment: @rallyboy - I'm glad I could help, and I hope you now understand how to use `keyup` to check for different keys, but from your comment above I think this is the wrong way to trigger your button's fade in. I think what you really want is to test not which key was pressed but whether your textarea is empty. If not empty fade in your button. You should probably test this on keyup, paste (which won't trigger a key event if done via the menu) and on drag'n'drop, which I'm assuming will give a mouseup (I've never tested it). So instead of `.keyup` try `.bind("keyup paste mouseup", function() { });`

Comment: Yes but then shift doesn't count as a letter and I want when textarea aint empty.

Comment: Isn't that what I just said in my last comment? In your event handler forget about testing which key(s) were pressed and just check the contents of the textarea: if not empty fade in the button.

Answer (score 0):

`onkeypress` or `onkeydown` ?

You can read in more detail the [key press events here](http://www.javascriptkit.com/jsref/eventkeyboardmouse.shtml).

**EDIT:**
Correct me if I'm wrong but you're confusing the actual KEY Codes with the event. The actuall event you're looking for is `onkeyup` and then you have to check if the key matches the range you want.

Have a look into the actual [browsers and keys support here](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/keys.html).

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#textarea').keypress(function(e){
       if(e.which >= 65 && e.which <= 90)
             $('#div2').fadeIn();
     }
);
```

That says on keypress, check if the character code is a letter (between 65 for 'a' and 90 for 'z'), then fade in the div2.

Answer (score 0):

The following will handle either a lowercase or uppercase (with or without Caps Lock) keypress event:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#txtInput').keypress(function (e) {
            var keycode = e.keyCode || e.which;
            if (((keycode >= 65) && (keycode <= 90)) || ((keycode >= 97) && (keycode <= 122))) {
                alert('Letter has been pressed');
            }
        });
    });
```

**jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/y5yuG/**